# Chrome: Can not change/delete/manage password/username on Google Dashboard

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-accounts

Well I am in a very awkward situation right now with updated Google Chrome. Previously it was possible to change/manage the saved password for specific sites, also, you could view the list of sites which were listed under **Never save passwords for this site** and manually remove those sites from that list as per your wish.
[image]

But now this is all gone in new version and all you have is your data saved on something called Google DashBoard, which looks like this:

[image]

So in this dashboard I cant not manage/edit/delete saved passwords manually for any site or remove website from list **Never Saved**. This is kind of frustrating and I googled about it but did not get any solution. Why would Google come up with such changes which puts users helpless situation? :(

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The Dashboard is not the place to manage your Chrome passwords. How did you come to this conclusion? As always, click on the wrench icon if you want to manage your browser passwords. There's a raft of information on Google's own support pages: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95606 ... My search criteria for this link was "chrome change saved password" and I clicked the first link.

Comment: I appreciate your help but that question is outdated. In new Chrome you dont get **Manage saved passwords** option. So you can't manually remove it.

Comment: You're wrong. I've got 21.0.1180.79 and it works exactly the way I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard holds all your Google account related data. Chrome's password management is there at  `chrome://chrome/settings/passwords` page.

[image]